# How to cache data after fetching from server?

Tags: android

I am using OkHttp library for networking request in app.Every time app opens
it sends request to the server which takes some time to load data in my app.
What I want is:

1) save data locally after fetching from server for fast loading.

2) Check for a new data if updated on server and fetch it again and save it 
   locally.

I have not done this kind of task before please guide me with the best possible solution of my problem. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: use [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room).

Comment: as John said, use Room database. Also, depending on your specific use, you could also cache certain data using `LRU`(Least recently used) cache. [LRU](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache)

Comment: Can  use Room without using it in MVVM architecture.

Comment: Room does not  force you to use MVVM

Comment: So how can I add data in Room after fetching it from server.